# SFML - Move object towards coord

Tags: c++, move, sfml

so I am working on an AI system with C++ and SFML in which I want the enemies to follow the player. Im going to create it so the enemies are moving towards the point at which the player was 30 frames ago (so it will constantly updating). But my question is simple, what is the math behind getting the enemy to move to a specific point? Like let's say the player is at (230, 400) and the enemy is at (100, 200) how do I get the enemy (using the .move() function with a speed of 3) to move to that point? Any help would be fantastic!

---UPDATED BELOW WITH CURRENT CODE FOR HANDLING MOVEMENT-----

```
float angle = atan2(v2iEnemyPos[1].y - rsPlayer.getPosition().y, v2iEnemyPos[1].x - rsPlayer.getPosition().x);
    angle =angle * 180 / (atan(1) * 4);
   sf::Vector2f newpos((cos(angle))*2, (sin(angle))*2);
    std::cout << newpos.x << " " << newpos.y << std::endl;
    rsEnemy[1].move(newpos.x, newpos.y);
    rwWinOne.draw(rsPlayer);
    rwWinOne.display();
    rwWinOne.clear();
```

Comment: That depends on how you want the enemy to behave. If you make the enemy move directly towards the player in a straight line, the player may have a difficult time avoiding the enemy. You have to consider that first before you begin coding.

Comment: Thats true, but I can use nodes to make it later have a more curved path, but im still going to have to know how to move the enemy to a position, no?

Comment: In its most basic form, `position += speed * Vector2(cos(angle), sin(angle))`.

Comment: @remyabel thank you, i think im starting to get it, but how do you multiply a vector by a constant such as 2? Do you mean 2 * Vector2.x and 2 * vector2.y?

Comment: Speed can either be a Vector2 (if the x and y are different), or a scalar (in which case it's equivalent to what you said.)

Comment: @remyabel 'float angle = atan2(v2iEnemyPos[1].y - rsPlayer.getPosition().y, v2iEnemyPos[1].x - rsPlayer.getPosition().x);
        angle =angle * 180 / (atan(1) * 4);
       sf::Vector2f newpos((cos(angle))*2, (sin(angle))*2);
        std::cout << newpos.x << " " << newpos.y << std::endl;
        rsEnemy[1].move(newpos.x, newpos.y);
        rwWinOne.draw(rsPlayer);
        rwWinOne.display();
        rwWinOne.clear();'

Comment: @remyabel oops misclick there, il add the code I use to handle the movement to the original post

Comment: @remyabel so this code here causes the movement to be a weird, player is affecting the movement but its not moving toward player

Comment: Game logic shouldn't be based on frames, it should be based on time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction to move your enemy into is simply the difference between the player position and the enemy position. However, you want the enemies to move with constant speed, so you need to normalize the result. This will give you the direction as a vector of length 1.

```
Vector2u direction = normalize(player.getPosition() - enemy.getPosition());
```

You can now multiply this direction by the speed constant of that enemy's type. The result is a vector with it's length depending on the speed factor instead of the distance to the player. Just use the result to move your enemy.

```
enemy.move(speed * direction);
```

However, you perform that once a frame and framerates can vary between machines and configurations. Therefore, you should add a the elapsed time since the last move call, which might be your frame time, as factor to the equation. This way, if a frame takes a longer than usual, the enemy will be moved further to comprehend this, and vice versa.

```
// Initialize a timer
sf::Clock clock;

// Get elapsed time at the beginning of a frame
// I multiply this by target framerate to get a value around one
float delta = clock.restart().asSeconds() * 60;

// Move all objects based on elapsed time
Vector2u direction = normalize(player.getPosition() - enemy.getPosition());
enemy.move(delta * speed * direction);
```

By the way, basic knowledge of linear algebra is needed very often in game development, so you might pay out to attend an online course.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the elapsed time (since last frame) - dt - in your calculation.

The enemy has a given speed: enemy_velocity.

I won't use the move() function, but the SetPosition().

You have to calculate the new position of the enemy:

```
enemy.x += dt * enemy_velocity * cos(angle);
enemy.y += dt * enemy_velocity * sin(angle);
```

And affect it with SetPosition().

Comment: What would he need the angle for? If I understand this correctly, he's just trying to move point A towards B, thus moving by `speed * normalize(B - A)`.

Comment: Yes you're right, danijar. I've just seen he's using angle and use them too, but your solution is better !

Comment: @danijar Thank you! Not only did that fix the movement but made it way more smooth, thank you!